# os.path.join not properly formatting path

Tags: python, windows

I'm writing a command-line directory navigator for Windows in Python and struggling a bit with os.path.join. Here's, in essence, what I'm trying to do:

```
abspath = "C:\Python32\Projects\ls.py"
abspath = abspath.split('\\')
print(abspath) #this prints ['C:', 'Python32', 'Projects', 'ls.py']

if(options.mFlag):  
        print(os.path.join(*abspath)) #this prints C:Python32\Projects\ls.py
        m = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(*abspath))) #this throws an exception
```

The problem is that os.path.join is not inserting a '/' after 'C:' and I can't figure out why. Any help?

Edit: In case anyone in the future comes here looking for a solution, I just added os.sep after "C:" instead of hardcoding a backslash and that worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> Note that on Windows, since there is a current directory for each drive, `os.path.join("c:", "foo")` represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

It's a little hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish, since all your code seems to be aiming at is to split the path and then put it back together exactly the way it was, in which case why split it in the first place?  But maybe [`os.path.splitdrive`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive) will help you?  It splits the drive letter from the path.

Comment: The point of this block is to make the program platform independent. Prior to inserting this function, the code wasn't executing properly in OSX. Thanks for the tip, I'll try splitdrive.

Comment: @benjaminhkaiser: Another thing you can do is use `/` as a path separator instead of \.  This will still work on Windows but will also work on other platforms.

Comment: So how do we get it to add the slash correctly?  `os.path.join(os.getenv("SystemDrive"), 'somepath')` == `'C:somepath'`

Comment: @endolith: I guess you could do `os.path.join(os.getenv("SystemDrive"), '/', 'somepath')`.  Or, as suggested in the question, do the same but use `os.sep` instead of `'/'`.

Answer (score 3):

The docs ( http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) specify this behaviour:

> Note that on Windows, since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

Comment: Is there an easy fix or should I manually put the backslash in (or just insert os.sep)? I just feel like that would defeat the purpose of using os.path.join.

Comment: A possible solution is not to split the path manually, but rather to use `os.path.split`. This will correctly not remove the first `\` from between the drive letter and the root directory.

Comment: @benjaminhkaiser: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm trying to make the code platform-independent. The abspath is passed in as a string and I want this function to dissect it and put it back together properly for the operating system it's using.